# how to display pi character in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, pi

I want to add Pi symbil at run time..bascially want to append with string at run time...any one has any idea how to do that? is there any ascii code to do that? code snippet will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *stringwithpi = [@"anystring" stringByAppendingString:@"\u03C0"];
NSLog(@"TEST  : %@", stringwithpi);
```

Basically, use unicode "\u03C0" to append PI.
Specifically, for cocos2d

```
NSString *labelpi = [@"lifeof" stringByAppendingString:@"\u03C0"];
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:labelpi fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
```

Tested successfully on iOS 6.0 simulator.